# How to create a function to extract columns from a data frame and create another using R?

Tags: r, function, loops

I need to create a function to make my workflow better. I already create a code, but I need to repeat several times and change the number according to the `mat[i]` columns. I mean, if I'm going to create another matrix for `mat2`, I need to replace in all my code, the number `1` to `2`, for `mat3`: `2` to `3`, for `mat4`: `4` to `5`.

I have the data frame below (it is not my real data):

```
year <- c(rep(1998:2001, 4))
Age <- c(rep(15:18, 4))
mat1 <- c(rep(0.01, 16))
mat2 <- c(rep(0.012, 16))

df <- data.frame(year, Age, mat1, mat2)
```

I need to create `n` final numeric matrices, one for each `mat(i)`, (i = 1, 2,...,n). The rows would be the `age` and in the columns `year`.

I got the result that I wanted using the code below:

```
library(dplyr)
mat1 <- #selecting just intensities of order 1 and creating matrices
  dplyr::select(df, Age, year, mat1) #choosig the variables that I want to keep %>% 
  spread(year, mat1)

names(mat1)[c(2:5)] <- paste0("year ", names(mat1[2:5])) #change colnames as it is in the model
mat1[ ,1] <- paste0("age ", mat1[,1]) #alter the row from column "age"

mat_oe1 <- data.matrix(mat1[2:5])
dimnames(mat_oe1) <- list(c(mat1[,1]), #row names
                        c(names(mat1[2:5])))#columns names

#Saving as txt to read in the model later
write.table(mat_oe1, file = "mat_oe1.txt", sep = "\t",
            row.names = T, col.names = T)
```

The final result (which must be equal this to be inserted in a model that is already created) that I got is for `mat1`. For example, this result below it is for all the results for the variable `mat1`:

```
view(mat1)
        year 1998  year 1999  year 2000  year 2001
age 15   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01
age 16   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01
age 17   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01
age 18   0.01        0.01       0.01       0.01


view(mat2)
        year 1998  year 1999    year 2000    year 2001
age 15   0.012        0.012       0.012       0.012
age 16   0.012        0.012       0.012       0.012
age 17   0.012        0.012       0.012       0.012
age 18   0.012        0.012       0.012       0.012
```

Comment: what is "mat" in the second line? If it's the text above, remember to always put a reproducible version of the dataframe you're using `dput()` or `read.table`.  Also I only get 5 columns after the `select` and `spread` steps, not 16 as the next lines imply

Comment: It is missing some things because I posted the code that I have been using in my real data. I've simplified now, I thing. ```mat``` was the original data. I updated to the name ```df```. Thanks

Comment: How do you get all those decimal digits with `rep(0.1, ...)`? And what is your question as you appear to have working code? What do you need to repeat in *but I need to repeat several times*?

Comment: Those decimal digits aren't the original ones. It is just an example. I have the code but I need to repeat 40 times, and every time I need to change the file names.

Comment: Usage of `spread()` leads to an error.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need

```
library(reshape2)
df$mat <- df$mat1+df$mat2
dcast(df,Age~year,value.var = "mat",sum)
```

**EDIT**

```
#df that you provided
structure(list(year = c(1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 1998L, 1999L, 
2000L, 2001L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 
2001L), Age = c(15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 15L,   
16L, 17L, 18L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L), mat1 = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), 
mat2 = c(0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 
0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12)), .Names = c("year", 
"Age", "mat1", "mat2"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

first seperate the `df` into two dataframe by column which contains `mat` and 
    `no mat`

```
library(reshape2)
library(zoo)

df_no_mat <-  df[ , -which(names(df) %in% grep("mat", names(df), value = TRUE))]
#df_no_mat OUTPUT head
year    Age
1998    15
1999    16
2000    17
2001    18
1998    15
1999    16

df_mat <-  df[ , which(names(df) %in% grep("mat", names(df), value = TRUE))]
#df_mat OUTPUT head
mat1    mat2
 0.1    0.12
 0.1    0.12
 0.1    0.12
 0.1    0.12
 0.1    0.12
 0.1    0.12
```

Loop and spread which saves the df in a list

```
datalist = list()

for(i in names(df_mat)){
    df_no_mat$i <- df_mat[,i]
    datalist[[i]] <- dcast(df_no_mat,Age~paste0('year ',year),value.var = "i",mean)
    datalist[[i]] <- na.aggregate(datalist[[i]]) 
}
```

Access you df created for mats by using `datalist$mat1 or datalist[[1]]` and `datalist$mat2 or datalist[[2]]`

```
#Output
$mat1
Age year 1998   year 1999   year 2000   year 2001
15  0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01
16  0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01
17  0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01
18  0.01    0.01    0.01    0.01

$mat2
Age year 1998   year 1999   year 2000   year 2001
15  0.012   0.012   0.012   0.012
16  0.012   0.012   0.012   0.012
17  0.012   0.012   0.012   0.012
18  0.012   0.012   0.012   0.012
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is not. I don't need to sum the values.

Comment: from where are you getting those values in years..your input and output doesn't match at all....anyway i have edited the answer have look and let me know if it works